# Stopping Vue with veevalidate returning unexpected token export?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

Nuxt with server side rendering. Typescript and vee-validate 3.4.9.

This code is fine

```
extend('positive', value => {
  return value >= 0;
});
```

Add the default then I get the Unexpected token 'export' error

```
extend('required', { ...required });
```

What I have read so far is that this is a transpile error?

Comment: Please, provide all necessary information, not just snippets. Please, provide the whole error, including stack. What is the context for this code? The obvious difference is that another snippet has `required`. *Add the default* - what is the meaning of this?

Comment: That is the only line you have to change and nuxt breaks in a basic generated nuxt site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpile did fix it in *nuxt.config.js*

```
build: {
    transpile: [
        'vee-validate'
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/rules.html#importing-the-rules

> You can fix that by either ignoring vee-validate/dist/rules from the
> transpilation process or importing rules from
> vee-validate/dist/rules.umd instead

```
import { required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules.umd";
```

the above added `umd` works for me

BTW, I think you may just want `extend('required', required);` instead?